# Clickinum Is Not Picking Up Instagram Button

Tags: python, automation, clicknium

**Recently, I've been trying to fix this program using Clickinum**, which takes YT shorts and uploads them onto Instagram, and I need to automatically open up a new Instagram page, go to the account profile, and then upload a video. I've managed to nail the first part.

However, it's the last part that is currently troubling me, specifically clicking or finding the upload or create button.

I've been trying to use Clickinum to click on the "create" button on Instagram; however, it doesn't seem to be working.

Basically, when I capture the button and try to validate it manually, it seems to work. However, when I try to use the capture in the script, for some reason, it tells me it can't detect the element anymore.

**Heres the code for the instagram part:**

```
import os
from time import sleep
from clicknium import clicknium as cc, locator,ui

print("Instagram Workflw. Started")
def upload(caption, cover_img_file, video_file):
    print("Insta Checkpoint1")
    tab = cc.chrome.open(url="https://instagram.com/")
    print("Insta Checkpoint2")
    tab.goto("instagram.com/logintttt/") #Add your instagram url here
    print("Insta Checkpoint3")
    for i in range(10):
        sleep(1)
        print("Seconds Passed = "+str(i))
    #cc.chrome.open("instagram.com/logintttt/").find_element(locator.chrome.instagram.svg_add_post).click()
    tab.find_element(locator.chrome.instagram.svg_add_post).click() #find_element(locator.chrome.instagram.svg_add_post).click()
    print("Insta Checkpoint4")
    sleep(3)
    tab.find_element(locator.chrome.instagram.button_select_file).click(by='mouse-emulation')
    sleep(3)
    ui(locator.chrome.edit_file).set_text(video_file, by='set-text')
    sleep(3)
    ui(locator.chrome.button_open).click(by='control-invocation')
    sleep(3)
    tab.find_element(locator.chrome.instagram.button_next).click()
    sleep(3)
    tab.find_element(locator.chrome.instagram.button_selectfromcomputer).click(by='mouse-emulation')
    sleep(3)
    ui(locator.chrome.edit_file).set_text(cover_img_file, by='set-text')
    sleep(3)
    ui(locator.chrome.button_open).click(by='control-invocation')
    sleep(3)
    tab.find_element(locator.chrome.instagram.button_next).click()
    sleep(3)
    tab.find_element(locator.chrome.instagram.textarea).click(by='mouse-emulation')
    tab.find_element(locator.chrome.instagram.textarea2).set_text(caption)
    sleep(3)
    tab.find_element(locator.chrome.instagram.button_share).click()
    sleep(3)
    tab.wait_appear(locator.chrome.instagram.h2_yourposthasbeenshared, wait_timeout=150)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cover_image = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "media", "logo.png")
    video_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "media", "clicknium_introduction.mp4")
    upload('Clicknium introduction', cover_image, video_file)
```

**This is the error I am getting:**

```
PS D:\Program Files (x86)\User\Personal Stuff\Python\Download-Youtube-Videos-EditClips-Auto-Upload-To-TikTok-Twitter-Instagram-main\Download-Youtube-Videos-EditClips-Auto-Upload-To-TikTok-Twitter-Instagram-main> & C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe "d:/Program Files (x86)/User Files/Personal Stuff/Python/Download-Youtube-Videos-EditClips-Auto-Upload-To-TikTok-Twitter-Instagram-main/Download-Youtube-Videos-EditClips-Auto-Upload-To-TikTok-Twitter-Instagram-main/amp/upload_instagram.py"
Instagram Workflw. Started
Insta Checkpoint1
Insta Checkpoint2
Insta Checkpoint3
Seconds Passed = 0
Seconds Passed = 1
Seconds Passed = 2
Seconds Passed = 3
Seconds Passed = 4
Seconds Passed = 5
Seconds Passed = 6
Seconds Passed = 7
Seconds Passed = 8
Seconds Passed = 9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Program Files (x86)\User Files\Personal Stuff\Python\Download-Youtube-Videos-EditClips-Auto-Upload-To-TikTok-Twitter-Instagram-main\Download-Youtube-Videos-EditClips-Auto-Upload-To-TikTok-Twitter-Instagram-main\amp\upload_instagram.py", line 45, in <module>
    upload('Clicknium introduction', cover_image, video_file)
  File "d:\Program Files (x86)\User Files\Personal Stuff\Python\Download-Youtube-Videos-EditClips-Auto-Upload-To-TikTok-Twitter-Instagram-main\Download-Youtube-Videos-EditClips-Auto-Upload-To-TikTok-Twitter-Instagram-main\amp\upload_instagram.py", line 16, in upload
    tab.find_element(locator.chrome.instagram.svg_add_post).click() #find_element(locator.chrome.instagram.svg_add_post).click()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\clicknium\core\service\invokerservice.py", line 157, in wrapper
    raise exception;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
clicknium.common.models.exceptions.ElementNotFoundError: Element can not be found.
PS D:\Program Files (x86)\User Files\Personal Stuff\Python\Download-Youtube-Videos-EditClips-Auto-Upload-To-TikTok-Twitter-Instagram-main\Download-Youtube-Videos-EditClips-Auto-Upload-To-TikTok-Twitter-Instagram-main>
```

To fix this problem I tried using chat-gpt however, it came up with ideas that didnt help which was by using the selenium driver and also instead of an fixed loading time an dynamic one which will click the button as soon as it has loaded in.

This failed however, and I am trying to just fix it so that it detects the element and actually clicks it without fail.

****Attached an Image of the Captured "Create" Element**:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6StU.png)

Any help/ideas or anything is much appriciated.